# Having a problem with starting a setTimer for a function and stopping it JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, addeventlistener

Hello I want to make it so that I can start and stop a function with a keypress and I've been having a problem with setting a timer on my function and I don't know why the addEventListener is giving me errors like this is not a function or window not defined
I tried to switch window with global because I'm using node.js but it still doesn't work

```
var refreshIntervalId;

window.addEventListener("onkeydown", keyDown, true);
window.addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);

function keyDown() {
  var e = window.event;
  switch (e.keyCode) {
    case 115:
      start();
      break;
    case 83:
      stop();
      break;
  }
}

function start() {
  stop();
  refreshIntervalId = setInterval(function () {
    var data = Data();
    data.then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }, 5000);
}
function stop() {
  if (refreshIntervalId != null) {
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    refreshIntervalId = null;
  }
}
```

Comment: No such event as `onkeydown`, it's `keydown`

Comment: _"because i'm using node.js"_ - Then why is this question not flagged with `nodejs`? Node has no windows so why should there be a `window` object? And what do you expect to happen with `keydown`/`keyup` in a console/CLI?

Comment: _"is giving me errors like this is not a function or window not defined"_ -> [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"Describe the problem. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what **the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it**."_

Comment: ...And, functions can only be stopped by throwing an error or returning. They can't be paused. You most likely need an AJAX request if you want to do another operation while the function is running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a remake of your original code:

- Use only the `"keydown"` Event.
- Set the `itv` to `undefined` inside the `stop()` function
- Don't use `evt.keyCode`. You're writing code mainly for developers and a future self. Use `evt.key` instead, or eventually `evt.code` (if other keys like ShiftKey matter)
- Use `evt.repeat` to check whether the user is long-pressing a key

```js
let itv;
let dummyIndex = 0;
const Data = () => Promise.resolve(`Dummy data ${++dummyIndex}`);

const start = () => {
  stop();
  dummyIndex = 0;
  itv = setInterval(() => {
    Data().then((res) => console.log(res));
  }, 1000);
  console.log("Started");
};

const stop = () => {
  if (!itv) {
    return; // Do nothing (Already stopped).
  }
  clearInterval(itv);
  itv = undefined;
  console.log("Stopped");
};

const keyDown = (evt) => {
  if (evt.repeat) {
    return; // Do nothing on long keydown
  }
  switch (evt.key) {
    case "F4":
      start();
      break;
    case "s":
      stop();
      break;
  }
};

addEventListener("keydown", keyDown);
```

```html
Click here to focus.<br>
Hit "F4" to Start<br>
Hit "s" to Stop<br>
Or hit "F4" to Restart
```

PS: needless to say, the above JavaScript is specifically intended for the ***browser*** environment, not NodeJS.